# django development of data over time

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a web application where a user gets experience for finishing particular tasks.

I´m using Django-REST and REACT for frontend.

I would like to show statistics, where the user can see the graph how much experience he has gained each month. What is the best approach to save data?

I was thinking about creating a model, which will store information about a month and user experience. Then at the end of the month, I would run a script that will collect all this information for each user.

I would like to know if there is something, that could go wrong or if there is a better way, how to achieve the same result, please let me know.

Thanks for every advice!

Answer (score 0):

What you are planning to implement seems like a dynamic dashboard(a very toned down version of it), what you might want to do is store the user experience or any else data you might want to display on the dashboard as a report/result in models and then use api's to fetch relevant data for your dashboard/graphs. Making the api's itself to fetch the data for the dashboard is not something you need to worry about(in general). The main issue would be performance...

Basically there are two ways to improve api performance :
1) Using raw queries (how you execute queries in Postgres/SQL shell); requires advance knowledge of DB queries, annotations, creating functions, et cetera.
2) Using ORM (how django executes raw queries under the hood); doesn't require advance knowledge which is why leveraging on ORM.But most of the ORMs are slow and executing N+1 queries in most cases.So here are some links the one may want to refer for the same:

*https://medium.com/kolonial-no-product-tech/pushing-the-orm-to-its-limits-d26d87a66d28

*https://medium.com/@chakrabortypritish/django-optimization-how-to-avoid-memory-mishaps-1e55b2aa947c

Tools to monitor the performance:

- https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/
- https://github.com/WoLpH/django-statsd
- https://scoutapm.com/blog/monitoring-a-django-app-with-scout

In a nutshell :-
 Integrate performance monitor, try using annotations and create managers.

For the frontend side since you are using React as the framework you can take a look at https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design it's an UI library for react and might help you out based on your requirements.

Comment: If you wish for a simpler implementation then take a look at this :- https://medium.com/better-programming/prettify-python-django-with-beautiful-visual-charts-836fe6646305?source=grid_home---------0-49----------55f1c20aba7a-------18---f0ae8c07_e626_4505_bda9_373e10c1b0e1--4